# Defining a delegate as a function pointer

Tags: c#, delegates, unmanaged, function-pointers

I am using a delegate which calls an unmanaged function pointer. This causes the Garbage Collector to collect it before it is used, as described in the CallbackOnCollectedDelegate MDA page on MSDN: [MSDN page for CallbackOnCollectedDelegate MDA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43yky316.aspx).

The resolution states that I have to marshal the appropriate delegate as an unmanaged function pointer. My initial reflex was to use:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
public delegate void EntityCallback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)] IntPtr entity);
```

However, the C# compiler won't let me marshal a delegate, even if this is the suggested resolution by MSDN. Moreover, the MSDN page only shows an example of the problem being thrown, but not one of the resolution.

How could I marshal my delegate as an unmanaged function pointer or keep it from being GCed?

**EDIT**: As suggested, I created a reference of the callback. Therefore, my code changed from/to:

```
// From:
foo.SetCallback(new EntityCallback(bar));

// To:
call = new EntityCallback(bar); // Referenced in class
foo.SetCallback(call);
```

Now this does work - but only in Debug mode. When I switch to Release, it crashes at the same point. Why is that?

**EDIT 2**: More complete code snippet:

```
public class Test
{
    private EntityCallback Call;

    private void Bar(System.IntPtr target)
    {
        ...
    }

    public Entity Foo { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        this.Foo = new Body.Sphere() { Visible = false }; // Irrelevant
        this.Foo.CollisionType = 3; // Irrelevant

        this.Call = new EntityCallback(this.Bar);

        this.Foo.SetCallback(this.Call, EntityCallbackType.Collision);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't read it correctly.  You must do this:

> ...change your code to keep a reference
>   to that delegate on the managed side
>   for the lifetime of the marshaled
>   unmanaged function pointer.

In other words, just store a reference to the delegate instance in your class and make sure the class object survives long enough.  Use a static if you really have to.

Comment: Edited, see my new question please.

Comment: I cannot tell from the very meager code snippet how long the object that stores "call" is going to be around.

Comment: I still can't tell what is keeping the Test object alive.  Add a destructor to the class and log something so you know when it gets collected.

Comment: I know for sure Test isn't being disposed, as Test is responsible of a graphical aspect of the program - if it wasn't there, the graphics wouldn't update. Therefore, it's safe to assume that Test doesn't get disposed at all.

Comment: So you are getting the MDA warning, even though you are 100% sure that there is in fact a reference to the delegate?  Whose wrong, the debugger or you?  If you suspect the debugger then turn the warning off, Debug + Exceptions.

Comment: I'm not getting the MDA warning anymore, as since this is in release, I just get "... has stopped working". It could be anything, to be honest. Sorry for not being clear, I am sure not questioning the debugger, only I have none in this case.

Comment: Sigh, you need to start a new question.  This problem is completely unrelated.