# Threading trouble with windows forms

Tags: c#, multithreading

Alright so I am having a hard time figuring out how to wait for the thread to finish before continuing along with the code without freezing up the windows form..

example code:

```
var ct = new System.Threading.Thread(solve);
ct.IsBackground = true;
ct.Name = "Solving";
//start our thread
ct.Start();
ct.Join();
label33.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { label33.Text = "Submitting..."; });
clickPost("name", textBox27.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `ct.Join()` only has one purpose - to block until the thread in question completes.

If you don't want to block, you need to handle notification of the completion of the background "work" via some other mechanism, such as an event.

This is greatly simplified for Windows Forms by using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), which does the notification for you (on the correct user interface thread).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly all you need is to create callback for some async operation.
You can use delegate's BeginInvoke callback parameter. Keep in mind the delegate and its callback will be executed in own thread:

```
Action backgroundAction = new Action(DoAction);
backgroundAction.BeginInvoke(ActionCallback, null);

private void DoAction()
{
    //some background task
}

private void ActionCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
   //will be executed after
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `EndInvoke` somewhere?

Comment: EndInvoke can be used if you need to get some result from DoAction(). In my example DoAction() declared as void. If you use another delegate with return value you right the only way to get this result is using EndInvoke.

Comment: I'm having a problem with Action... "Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: Yes, I forgot about exceptions... Thank you.

Comment: I wonder where you get this error? If you use my code there are no such error. I dont use generic version of Action.

Comment: I am using your code exactly and its giving me the generic type error i said when i try to compile.

Comment: What version of .NET Framework you use? Action class appeared in 3.5. So my example works on 3.5 Framework or higher.

Comment: ah yes, that was the issue. I am now using a higher framework and is not throwing any errors. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same except have the ActionCallback code to happen within the ui and not within the thread?

Comment: There are many threads on SO where this problem was discussed. For example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599902/c-how-to-force-calling-a-method-from-the-main-thread-by-signaling-in-some-wa)