# C# Accessing form control from different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, listview, thread-safety

I've been looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls and other Stack Overflow questions for a good  long while now to figure out how to use thread-safe methods to access a ListView controls from different threads.

Here's how I want to implement parallel tasks in my program:
I call four different methods in parallel with:

```
Parallel.Invoke(ProcessLow, ProcessMed, ProcessHigh, ProcessSprint);
```

Each method searches through the same `collection` (`data[i].Knots`) with a for loop and looks for a different range of values within that `collection`, then if one of the methods finds an appropriate value within the range it's looking for it adds the time and knots (`data[i].Time`, `data[i].Knots`) to its respective `ListView` (the methods write to `lstvLow`, `lstvMed`, `lstvHigh` and `lstvSprint` respectively). At the moment it's just throwing the exception for non-thread safe code. Also will it break if I have different threads just reading off the same collection? (if so, how can I work around this?)

tldr: Parallel processing is new to me, how do I make a thread-safe call to a windows form control.
And also if you can, point me in the direction of some good reading other than msdn for Parallel tasking.

edit: this is with winforms

Comment: WPF or winforms?

Comment: Winforms, sorry

Comment: Couple of options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599902/c-how-to-force-calling-a-method-from-the-main-thread-by-signaling-in-some-wa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you are new to multitasking. I hope my case study will help you. Create a windows form with next controls:

- `startButton`, `stopButton` as Button
- `minTextEdit`, `maxTextEdit` as TextEdit
- `listListView` as ListView

For startButton and stopButton use the appropriate methods: `startButton_Click` and `stopButton_Click`.

Full the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Thread0
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
        private List<int> lst = new List<int>();
        private bool isRun = false;

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isRun = true;
            stopButton.Enabled = true;
            startButton.Enabled = false;
            var tskMain = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    var tsk1 = Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            int max = 0;
                            int min = Int32.MaxValue;
                            lock (lst)
                            {
                                int num = _random.Next(1, 1000000);
                                lst.Add(num);
                                foreach (var x in lst)
                                {
                                    if (x > max) max = x;
                                    if (min > x) min = x;
                                }
                                listListView.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => listListView.Items.Insert(0, num.ToString())));
                            }
                            maxTextBox.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => maxTextBox.Text = max.ToString()));
                            minTextBox.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => minTextBox.Text = min.ToString()));

                            if (!isRun) break;

                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isRun = false;
            stopButton.Enabled = false;
            startButton.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When you click on the Start button, the stream create and run `tskMain` thread, which creates 8 more threads. In each of them, an integer is added to the list of values `lst`, and the search for the maximum and minimum values. The new number is also added to the `listListView`, and the maximum and minimum value in the corresponding `minTextEdit` and `maxTextEdit`.

For work it is convenient to use lambda expression.

`lock(lst) ...` blocks work with the list of values. One action per time, so that there are no exceptions.

And the `BeginInvoke` method allows you to call methods from threads for form elements that are in the main form stream. The `Action` is used to "transform" the lambda expression into a delegate method.

Inside each thread, the variable IsRun is checked, if its value becomes false, the thread execution stops.

Well, to ensure that everything is not very quickly use `.Sleep`

Comment: Cheers! That’s helped!

Answer (score 1):

To make thread safe call. use `Control.Invoke();` method. Assuming you have instance of `ListView mylistView;` you can write:

```
object result =  mylistView.Invoke(new Action(() => mylistView.DoSomething()));
```